D3 Timeline zooming with buttons
I am new to D3 so my knowledge of how it operates is very limited. I have this code that zooms in on a timeline that I changed from horizontal to vertical, so the y-axis has the dates. This code is in a file called zoom.js.
import * as d3 from 'd3'

let zoomLevel = 1
export default (config) => {
let {
    vueThis,
    vuetify,
    timeScale,
    view,
    draw,
} = config

return d3.zoom()
    .on('zoom', () => {

        let { k, x, y } = d3.event.transform

        let scale = d3.zoomIdentity
            .translate(0,y)
            .scale(k)
            .rescaleY(timeScale)

        view.call(draw(scale, vueThis, vuetify, zoomLevel))
    })
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 100])
}

From another js file I am supplying timeScale and the rest of the params. I need to list them here for the sake of code completion:
let width = viewWidth - margin.right - margin.left
let height = viewHeight// - margin.top - margin.bottom

let svg = selection
            .append('svg')
            .datum(data)
            .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 750)
let startDate = params[0].startDate
startDate = startDate ? new Date(startDate) : d3.min(events.map(e => e.start))
let endDate = params[0].endDate
endDate = endDate ? new Date(endDate) : d3.max(events.map(e => e.end))

let timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
                  .domain([startDate, endDate])
                  .range([0, width - 150])

let graph = svg
            .append('g')
            .classed('graph', true)
            .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left+50},${margin.top+10})`)
    
let view = graph.append('g')
                .classed('view', true);

Now, I just want to add button events to zoom in and out instead of the mouse wheel. I really thought I could follow from some example online that already does it but the examples I found that do this on a timeline are extremely limited (and since this is not a shape, scaleBy does not apply here). Only this: https://plnkr.co/edit/okXVOgQxWOLlwpZmLEzI?p=preview&preview and it's a really complex one.
I already have the button click triggered and it's value passed. Let's say it's "yearly" and "weekly" and they come in a new param called absLevel. How shall I amend the zoom event handler and invoke a transition command according to absLevel please? From the example linked, I figured it might have to be at the domain level where I change the start and end dates for the range but I still don't know enough D3 to implement it correctly. I tried amending the identity because that makes sense but then I don't know what goes in the zoomed function to render the changes.
Much appreciated.
